# How can I observe a property rather than the object it points to with WinJS?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

Hopefully I'm describing this correctly. I'm making a windows store app and I have the following setup

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("Model",
    {
        WorkOrders: new WinJS.Binding.List(),
        selectedWorkOrder: {}
    });
WinJS.Namespace.define("ViewModel",
    {
        WorkOrders: Model.WorkOrders,
        selectedWorkOrder: Model.selectedWorkOrder
    })
```

When the page is loaded an ajax request populates a list of WorkOrders, after they're populated a user can select one, at which point Model.selectedWorkOrder is set to one of the objects in Model.WorkOrder.

I want ViewModel.selectedWorkOrder to reflect whatever Model.selectedWorkOrder is, but it seems to bind only to the originally empty object, how can I make it bind to that property (even if the object changes, like a pointer).

I'm doing something like this to set the selectedWorkOrder

```
Model.selectedWorkOrder = results[i];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly.

What you're looking for is some kind of event to get in `ViewModel.selectedWorkOrder` whatever `Model.selectedWorkOrder` has, right?
If that's the case you could try [RxJS-WinJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rxjs-winjs) (which I'm honestly not too familiar with) or you could just make `ViewModel.selectedWorkOrder` a method that gets and returns whatever `Model.selectedWorkOrder` has at any given time.

Something like this:

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("Model",
{
    WorkOrders: new WinJS.Binding.List(),
    selectedWorkOrder: {}
});

var _getWorkItem = function(){
    return Model.selectedWorkItem;
}
WinJS.Namespace.define("ViewModel",
{
    WorkOrders: Model.WorkOrders,
    selectedWorkOrder: _getWorkItem
})
```